# How to find a sub directory using Regex in Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

Directory Location: /var/lib/messageFunction-7834bdfjsdfj783/data/snapshot

I have the above directory and I need to find if the directory exists using a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "/var/lib/messageFunction-*/data/snapshot" ]; then
echo NO FOLDER
else
echo FOLDER IS THERE
fi
```

The above script always returned "NO FOLDER" but the directory exists in the location. Can you guide how to regex to identify the subdirectory?

Thanks

Comment: `'*'` is not expanded within quotes. It is literally testing for the directory named `/var/lib/messageFunction-*/data/snapshot` which won't exist. An iterative solution, as below, is the proper approach, or use `find` and loop over the output (or `grep`, etc..) Also in pathname expansion `'*'` is part of filename globbing, not a REGEX...

Comment: What if there are multiple directories matching the glob `/var/lib/messageFunction-*/data/snapshot` ?

Comment: There is probably a better duplicate specifically about why not to quote `*` but I imagine you solved this already.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for but another solution how I would solve this.
First loop over all directories that match the first part and than check if the data/snapshot dirs are in there:

```
#!/bin/bash
for myDir in /var/lib/messageFunction-*; do
    if [ ! -d "$myDir/data/snapshot" ]; then
        echo "NO FOLDER"
    else
        echo "FOUND IN $myDir"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "find" command (not "ls" - agree):

```
if [[ -n $(find /var/lib/ --max-depth=0 -type d -name "messageFunction-*" 2>/dev/null) ]]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Not found"
fi
```

Where:

/var/lib/ (path for search)

--max-depth=0 (don't search in sub-directories)

-type d (search only directories)

-name "messageFunction-*" (directory wildcard name)

2>/dev/null (not catch error messages)

Comment: This solution won't differentiate between a file and a directory

Comment: No, [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs); it is hugely error-prone and unwieldy.

Comment: Agree "ls" - is bad idea, use "find" instead.